# While creating telegram bot, terminal was arguing for the 'text' in 8th line

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

```
import telebot
import config
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)
language = "kazakh"

keyboard1 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
item_kaz = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(text = "Қазақ тілі", callback_data = "kazakh")
item_rus = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(text = "Русский язык", callback_data = "russian")
keyboard1.add(item_kaz, item_rus)

keyboard2 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, True)
item_7 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(text = "7", callback_data = "7")
item_8 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(text = "8", callback_data = "8")
item_9 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(text = "9", callback_data = "9")
item_10 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(text = "10", callback_data = "10")
item_11 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(text = "11", callback_data = "11")
item_12 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(text = "12", callback_data = "12")
keyboard2.add(item_7, item_8, item_9, item_10, item_11, item_12)

keyboard3 = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, True)
item_1 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(text = "1", callback_data = "1")
item_2 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(text = "2", callback_data = "2")
item_3 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(text = "3", callback_data = "3")
item_4 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(text = "4", callback_data = "4")
keyboard3.add(item_1, item_2, item_3, item_4)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):
    sti = open('static/welcome.webp', 'rb')
    bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, sti)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, " Қош келдіңіз / Добро пожаловать, {0.first_name}!\nМенің атым / Я - <b>{1.first_name}</b>.Тілді таңдаңыз / Выберите язык.".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()), parse_mode='html', reply_markup=keyboard1)

def synyptar(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Сыныпты таңдаңыз / Выберите класс', reply_markup=keyboard2)

def toqsandar(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Тоқсанды таңдаңыз / Выберите четверть', reply_markup=keyboard3)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def lalala(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)

#RUN
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Hi guys, recently i have faced the unpleasent problem which is connected with the telegram. I would like to add Buttons by ReplyKeyboardMarkup, but the python does not give me the chance. Please if you understand, helpe to solve this issue.

```
item_kaz = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(text = "Қазақ тілі", callback_data = "kazakh")
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'text'
```

Comment: Which one do you want your bot to send? [these ones](https://core.telegram.org/bots#inline-keyboards-and-on-the-fly-updating) (inline) or [these](https://core.telegram.org/bots#keyboards) (reply-keyboard)  - in the later (reply-keyboards), you can't use `callback_data`

Answer (score 1):

There are few concepts in `python-telegram-bot`:

- `KeyboardButton` - **button** class for description of simple reply button, can be used just string instead. Example:

  ```py
  KeyboardButton(text='ABC')
  ```
- `ReplyKeyboardMarkup` - **container** class for KeyboardButtons accepts list of them or just one (string or object). Example:

  ```py
  ReplyKeyboardMarkup([
      'ABC',
      KeyboardButton(text='DEF'),
      KeyboardButton(text='GHI'),
  ])
  ReplyKeyboardMarkup('ABC')
  ReplyKeyboardMarkup(KeyboardButton(text='DEF'))
  ```
- `InlineKeyboardButton` - **button** class for description of Inline Button, can be used only using class, `callback_data` is not required. Example:

  ```py
  InlineKeyboardButton(text='ABC', callback_data="button_abc")
  ```
- `InlineKeyboardMarkup` - **container** class for InlineKeyboardButton contains list of them. Example:

  ```py
  InlineKeyboardMarkup([
      InlineKeyboardButton(text='ABC', callback_data="button_abc"),
      InlineKeyboardButton(text='DEF', callback_data="button_def"),
      InlineKeyboardButton(text='GHI', callback_data="button_ghi"),
  ])
  ```

In your case, you misused `InlineKeyboardMarkup` instead of `InlineKeyboardButton`. So you need to change:

```py
keyboard1 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(
    types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Қазақ тілі", callback_data="kazakh"),
    types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Русский язык", callback_data="russian"),
)
```